# Excel <-> Catia connection: tlb references issue

Tags: excel, vba, catia

I am writting an excel macro which need to cooperate with CATIA drawing "on the fly". It means it need to place some things on the drawing from excel sheet and get things from drawing to excel sheet on user demands. Sounds easy, but..
In my particular case CATIA is not installed locally but on the company's server. In order to get connected user needs to register it via "CNEXT.exe /regserver" command, looking first for path to CNEXT.exe on network disk. So he needs to launch command like: "**j:\appl...\CNEXT.exe /regsever**". In my macro I need to establish connection to CATIA object by referencing the *.tlb files via: Tools\References and choose apropriate Reference (in my case **CATIA V5 InfInterfaces Object Library** and **CATIA V5 DraftingInterfaces Object Library**)

#### References screenshot

[image: References screenshot]

It is still easy, now tricky part comes: Everything works properly as long as I am at work and network disks are available. Once I try to open this excel file outside, it hangs. I figured out that references I defined are indicating on *.tlb files which are stored in the same place CATIA is. :(
This excel file I am developing has to be shared with our suppliers who needs to fill in manualy worksheets they need to complete, as well as other people in my company which don't have access to CATIA to be able to review it. General idea is that macro should be run only by people using CATIA and manual modification of worksheets and review should be available for others. In current situation having no access to "j:..." network drive no one will be able to even open excel file, not mentioning launching macro I am writting.

My question is: Is it possible to force excel not to check references at lanuch and do it only by some step in one of the initialisation procedures? I wrote some code which is checking availability of CATIA, in which Excel could check these references.
Another idea is to embed somehow *.tlb files or they content in my excel file to be available permanently for anyone.

I was trying to add reference to *.tlb files inside of the code to indicate at the same *.tlb files but copied to some local directory on my computer (to be able to write code outside of the company), but I got an error message:

#### Error message - User-defined type not defined

[image: Error message - User-defined type not defined]

Small update - I've just red about early and late binding. I've made a test and write a code which declares CATIA object as Object, not as INFITF.Application. Now I can code without reference to any *.tlb files. Now issue is gone, but also intellisense is gone as well :( - I cannot imagine to write a code without it.
So one idea came to my mind, that I could code with references correctly indicating on the *.tlb files and then just before releasing the macro to overall usage I could exchange declaration from "CATIA specific" just to Object type, but that would require to write a macro to modify a macro to change these declarations for all instances in whole code :(:(:(.. help me, please..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to maintain two excel files
"master file" containing macro that communicates with catia and "data file" to store data.
"data file" will not have any macros that communicate with catia.

you can then use forms/file browsing VBA code in master file to browse and select "data-file", then you can easily read data-file and perform your operations.

I did it for a customer and believe me, it is easier than

> write a macro to modify a macro to change these declarations for all
>   instances in whole code